# Enabling mod_fcgid results in 403

Tags: apache-2.2, http-status-code-403, mod-fcgid

I have an EasyPHP 12.1 setup (latest) on Windows 7x64 and I'm trying to enable `mod_fcgid` for PHP. I have added the following in my `httpd.conf`

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so 
FcgidInitialEnv PHPRC "C:\progra~2\EasyPHP-12.1\php\php546x121028092509" 
AddHandler fcgid-script .php
FcgidWrapper "C:\progra~2\EasyPHP-12.1\php\php546x121028092509/php-cgi.exe" .php
```

and `Options ExecCGI Indexes FollowSymLinks` under `<Directory "${path}/www">`

I've made sure the paths are all good and set permissions on the entire `C:\progra~2\EasyPHP-12.1` and my `www` root to `Everyone - Allow All`.

Yet I still get 403 on all server(localhost) requests. Along with `Apache/2.4.2 (Win32) PHP/5.4.6 mod_fcgid/2.3.7` so I **know** mod_fcgid is enabled and is causing the 403.

Commenting out the above lines from `httpd.conf` makes it work again but is slower than death (which is why I wanted mod_fcgid). What could I be doing wrong?

edit:: error log

```
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host2.example.com] does not exist
[Mon Nov 05 23:00:38.244339 2012] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7072:tid 512] AH00455: Apache/2.4.2 (Win32) PHP/5.4.6 mod_fcgid/2.3.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Nov 05 23:00:38.245339 2012] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7072:tid 512] AH00456: Server built: Apr 20 2012 19:24:55
[Mon Nov 05 23:00:38.245339 2012] [core:notice] [pid 7072:tid 512] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\EASYPH~1.1\\Apache\\bin\\apache.exe -d C:/Program Files (x86)/EasyPHP-12.1/apache'
[Mon Nov 05 23:00:38.264340 2012] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7072:tid 512] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 8184
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host2.example.com] does not exist
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host2.example.com] does not exist
[Mon Nov 05 23:00:39.525412 2012] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8184:tid 524] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
```

Comment: What, exactly, does the error log say ?

Comment: @adaptr added error log. It doesn't add anything new to error log when I refresh the page and get 403.